# Java: How to create a file in the C:\ drive

Tags: java, file

I am trying to get the plain `C:\` path with java to store files in. I am having issues trying to figure this out as other resources didn't tell me, but they were using other paths. I know how to get the user's home like:

`File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home");`

but that only creates a new file in the user's main folder `C:\Users\<username>\`. How do I just create a file within the `C:\` directly in the drive?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29

Comment: Please read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Remember, you may not have the required permissions to write to the root drive of any hard disk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file object that points to exactly where you want.

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
```

Note that the '\' character needs to be escaped, thus the "\\".

To create a file there, you could do something like this:

```
File f = new File("C:\\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Note that, by this code you do not create file.

Comment: I'm trying to answer his question the best that I can, based on what I think he means.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a big idiot right now. Thanks for telling me.